# is there a way to alternate between two state machines?

Tags: unity

I'm programming an enemy on Unity that has two state machines, one controlling the "normal" behaviour of the enemy (that consists in three states: idle, patrol and chase) and another one controlling the battle behaviour of the enemy (that consists in three more states: attack, dodge and run away). I'm doing these state machines by using enums, like the following code

```
public enum StateMachines { NORMAL, BATTLE }
public enum NormalStates { IDLE, PATROL, CHASE }
public enum BattleStates { ATTACK, DODGE, RUNAWAY }
```

I want to loop between the Normal and Battle state machines but I have one problem that is they always get executed at the same time. Is there a way I can alternate between state machines through code in a single script (by conditions)? Thank you!

Comment: You make an state machine, when each state means that you will use one of these state machines. *I'm only half joking.*

Comment: What @Theraot describes is called "hierarchical state machines".

Comment: What's your state machine implementation like? Are you using any particular source for it?